# Was Apple's automatic disk ejection mechanism patented?

Tags: apple-macintosh, apple, disk-drive

I always though it was an awesome idea, but no one ever copied it. Even if more complicated than a standard eject mechanism, I guess it should not have been so outrageously expensive not to be considered by anyone else except Apple?

EDIT:

So, as people pointed out in the comments, the very idea of automatic ejection could not have been patented, only actual implementations. However, could have it instead been that what was patented was the software implementation/idea that by locking a floppy disk in the drive data integrity can be more easily enforced (let's ignore software bugs in the OS) without requiring the filesystem to do journaling or employ other performance-killing data integrity techniques?

Comment: I'd imagine it was patented, but there were other systems with mechanical disk ejection — Sun workstations for example.

Comment: Could the very idea of mechanical ejection be patented at all?

Comment: @user180940, a *specific* ejection mechanism could be patented; the fundamental idea of "automatically eject a floppy" can't.

Comment: @user180940 There is a specific class of patents designed to prevent exact copies (with measurements and component values if necessary to demonstrate an inventive step). Otherwise something as trivial as a spring or damper _could_ be inventive.

Comment: To add another one that had it, even for 5 1/4" floppies: The Sharp XC68000 also used to have "Soft Eject" (I guess that is what you're referring to - IMHO **all** disk eject is somehow *mechanical*)

Comment: There is an Apple patent here: http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US4466033 , but that's apparently for 5 1/4" drives according to the drawings. There's also a number of patents referring to "soft disk eject" from disk drive manufacturers like TEAC, Phillips and Sony, but those all post-date the Macintosh, as far as I can see. And none of those patents the generic idea of ejecting the disk using an electric actuator, but rather very *specific* methods how to do it (as @Mark rightly said above is not possible)

Comment: @user180940 And, related to your "awesome idea" statement: You have apparently never faced a disk stuck in a soft-eject drive that wouldn't eject. In situations like that, you might reconsider the "awesome" ;)

Comment: Also copied on some workstations, for example SparcStations, to enforce safe 'unmounting'.

Comment: Yes, it is most certainly possible to [claim a patent on an idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_brothers_patent_war).

Comment: I thought soft-eject was a terrific idea. Yes, the system sometimes crashed, but there were two workarounds:

* paper clip in the hole
* hold the mouse button down on restart

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the mechanical mechanism was patented. I can't find any evidence for a software patent.

It looks to be US patent [4466033](https://www.google.com/patents/US4466033) which was originally developed for the [Lisa's Twiggy drive](https://www.scribd.com/document/48544933/The-Legacy-of-the-Apple-Lisa-Personal-Computer-An-Outsider-s-View) but adapted for use in the [original Mac](http://ieeemilestones.ethw.org/Milestone-Proposal:Introduction_of_the_Apple_Macintosh_Computer,_1984) drive. Here is a quote from the second link:

> The Sony 3.5” micro-floppy was uniquely enhanced for the Macintosh by
>   incorporating performance, capacity and data integrity improvements 
>   which had been prototyped with a 5.25" floppy by way of five 
>   innovations [...] Fifth, the software-controlled floppy clamping and 
>   eject mechanism [Ref-3: '033 patent] - a signature characteristic of 
>   the Macintosh - insured file system integrity upon ejection of the 
>   floppy disk. The one-chip controller in combination with these five 
>   innovations created a fast, high capacity, reliable and low-cost
>   storage device that was unique to the Macintosh. The Macintosh
>   micro-floppy is also discussed on pp. 32, 39-42, 54 and 66-68 of the
>   February 1984 issue of Byte magazine

Here is a quote from the February 1984 issue of Byte magazine, page 39:

> In addition to the change to 80 tpi,  Apple contracted Sony to modify
>   the  drive in several other ways. Two  changes allow the Sony drive to
>   mimic the behavior of the Lisa  "twiggy" drives (which were originally
>   chosen for use in the Mac): disk  ejection under software control and 
>   variable disk-rotation speed. The first  change allows the Mac to
>   ensure that  a disk is correctly updated before it  is surrendered to
>   the user (that is,  you can't take a disk out of the drive  until the
>   Mac software permits it).

Andy Hertzfeld also corroborates Apple working closely with Sony on the drive in [this story](http://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?story=Hide_Under_This_Desk.txt), and a later Sony patent filed in 1988 [cites the original Apple patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US4991044).

Comment: Are you answering to the original question or to the hypothesis I wrote in the edited section ?

Comment: The title of the question. I've updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: I have referred to that patent in my comment above - The drawings clearly indicate a 5 1/4" drive, so it *could be* related to the Lisa, but no way to the Macintosh.

Comment: I've added more on the relationship between the Twiggy and Sony drives.